# Designing FSM's in VHDL using debounce with port map

Tags: process, vhdl, clock, fsm

I made my FSM in VHDL and now I want to use the debounce code with port mapping.
Though I have difficulties with the associations. In fact I want to insett the `debouncebutton` component among the signals that are driving the FSM.

```
entity myFSM is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LED : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end myFSM;

architecture Behavioral of myFSM is
        type state is (A, B, C);
        signal currentS, nextS: state;

        component debouncebutton
            Port ( clk      : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Clock of the board
           rst      : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Reset Button of the board          
           input    : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Push Button of the board
           output   : out std_logic     -- connect it to your circuit
          );
        end component;
begin
myFSM_comb: process (currentS, IN0, IN1, IN2)
begin
    case currentS is
        when A =>   LED <= "11111111";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        else            nextS<=A;
                        end if;
        when B =>   LED <= "11000011";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        else nextS<=B;
                        end if;
        when C =>   LED <= "00111100";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        else nextS<=C;
                        end if;
    end case;
end process;

myFSM_synch: process(CLK,RST)
begin 
    if (RST='1')        then    currentS<=A;
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then currentS<= nextS;
    end if;
end process ;

begin 

db0 : debounce
port map
(
    clk => CLK,
    rst => RST,
    input => IN0,
    output
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3):

I marked up your code by renaming IN0 to INP0 in the port declaration, declared a signal in the architecture with the name INO to keep from changing every occurrence of the name, removed an extraneous `begin` and renamed the instantiated component from `debounce` to `debouncebutton` to match the component declaration:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity myFSM is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INP0 : in  STD_LOGIC;  -- name changed
           IN1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LED : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end myFSM;

architecture Behavioral of myFSM is
        type state is (A, B, C);
        signal currentS, nextS: state;

        component debouncebutton
            Port ( clk      : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Clock of the board
           rst      : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Reset Button of the board          
           input    : in std_logic;     -- connect it to the Push Button of the board
           output   : out std_logic     -- connect it to your circuit
          );
        end component;

        signal IN0: std_logic;  --- added
begin
myFSM_comb: process (currentS, IN0, IN1, IN2)
begin
    case currentS is
        when A =>   LED <= "11111111";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        else            nextS<=A;
                        end if;
        when B =>   LED <= "11000011";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        else nextS<=B;
                        end if;
        when C =>   LED <= "00111100";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        elsif IN1 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        else nextS<=C;
                        end if;
    end case;
end process;

myFSM_synch: process(CLK,RST)
begin 
    if (RST='1')        then    currentS<=A;
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then currentS<= nextS;
    end if;
end process ;

-- begin  -- syntax error you have a begin before process myFSB_comb

db0 : debouncebutton  --- was debounce, needs to match component declaration
port map (
        clk => CLK,
        rst => RST,
        input => INP0,  -- renamed input port
        output=> IN0   --  newly declared signal INO
    );

end Behavioral;
```

This allowed the new input port `INP0` to be associated to the formal `input` on `debouncebutton` and the formal `output` to be connected to the newly declared signal IN0.

You could also go to all the trouble of simply declaring a new signal for the `output` association and changing instances of the name `IN0` other than the port declaration for myFSM.

Your modified code above analyzes. Without creating an entity/architecture pair for `debouncebutton` it can't be elaborated (or simulated).